# How to access graphics from .NET in Mathematica?

Tags: .netlink

I would like to use Wolfram.NETLink.MathKernel.Graphics to retrieve an image generated from a Mathematica command. Which Mathematica command do I use to do this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Wolfram.NETLink;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*
                MathKernel kernel = new MathKernel();
                kernel.Compute("ExportString[Graphics[Rectangle[]],{\"Base64\",\"EMF\"}]");
                byte[] decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(kernel.Result.ToString());
                File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\temp\\output.emf", decodedBytes);
            */

            MathKernel k = new MathKernel();
            k.CaptureGraphics = true;
            k.GraphicsFormat = "GIF";
            k.Compute("Show[Graphics[Rectangle[]]]");
            k.Graphics[0].Save("C:\\temp\\file.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried the same thing in C# and Oxygene .Net. Both have the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm presuming that you already have a command which generates a graphics and you're trying to retrieve it through the MathKernel. If so, try the following: 

 1. Set the `CaptureGraphics` Property on your MathKernel to true. 
 2. Run `MathKernel.Compute(command)` 
 3. If your command successfully returned a graphics (you could check by Mathematica notebook), you should be able to retrieve it inside the `MathKernel.Result`.

---

Edit: My apologies, `MathKernel.Result` would tell you whether it succeeded or not (with `$Failed` signifying a failure). If it succeeded, you can retrieve it via `.Graphics`. 
I'd also like to point out for anyone who may be dealing with this, that I've had to use the function `UseFrontEnd` quite frequently so that the graphics renders correctly.

Comment: CaptureGraphics Is set to true.
I'm using Import["image.png"] for my Mathematica command. mathKernel.Graphics.Length is still zero

Comment: Perhaps I need the full version of Mathematica to do this

Comment: Try this: Show[Import["Image.png"]]

Make sure that your .Result doesn't say $Failed as well.

Comment: Tried this, mathKernel.Result is null, and mathKernel.Graphics.Length is zero

Comment: Now the Result says -Image- in the debugger. but when I cast it as System.Drawing.Image the result is null

Comment: if it says Image in debugger, then you should check the Graphics whether it still says null.

Comment: may I request that you post your .NET code so we could get a better understanding of what may be happening?

Comment: Okay, I've confirmed that the GIF code in your edit works for me. `k.Result = "-Graphics-"`, and `k.Graphics = {System.Drawing.Image[1]}`. Looks like you do need the full version of Mathematica.

Comment: As a workaround, you could try using `Export[...]` in Mathematica to get Mathematica to export the file first into your file system. Then load the file back in C#.

Comment: Yep, tried that, it seems export is disabled in the trial version.

Answer (score 7):

To transfer an EMF graphic you can use this:

```
kernel.Compute("ExportString[Graphics[Rectangle[]],{\"Base64\",\"EMF\"}]");
byte[] decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(kernel.Result.ToString());
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Temp\\output.emf", decodedBytes);
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755810/converting-graphics-with-exportstring

also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542828/netlink-graphics-producing-png-instead-of-emf

GIF or JPEG graphics can be transferred via the `MathKernel.Graphics` property.

```
MathKernel k = new MathKernel();
k.CaptureGraphics = true;
k.GraphicsFormat = "GIF";
k.Compute("Show[Graphics[Rectangle[]]]");
k.Graphics[0].Save("C:\\Temp\\file.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

Note `Graphics` is an array.  Multiple images can be transferred in one operation.

Ref http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/NETLink/ref/net/Wolfram.NETLink.MathKernel.Graphics.html

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately this still does not work. I'm getting an index out of range exception because k.Graphics does not have any images.

Comment: The code snippet for Base64 encoding also gives an exception:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."