# Passing an image to Kernel via NETLink

Tags: image, mathlink-or-wstp, .netlink

I have created a specialized image analysis method in Mathematica that takes an image and returns a marked up image with some detection output.  In order to allow others to feed images into my analysis from arbitrary sources (databases, file systems, web interfaces, scanners, etc), I would like to wrap in a .NET application (preferably C#).

Is there any way to pass an image object from .NET into MathKernel via NETLink and handle it as an Image in the kernel?  I have found examples of how to get images out of MathKernel, but not the other direction.

I could write the image to a temporary file, but that seems sloppy.

Comment: In general you could pass data through a socket. Check [`SocketListen`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SocketListen.html)

Comment: Perhaps pass as base 64 string e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27956/363

Comment: In the J/Link implementation they use a `PutByteArray(...)` of the image data, presumably NETLink supplies a similar hook to `MLPutByteArray`? That will be fast and presumably pretty simple. Use `PutType("Image", 1)` or whatever the correct call is (can't remember) to wrap the data in `Image` first or whatever. I did this for my implementation of J/Link for python and remember it being pretty simple along those lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found through a lot of iterations that the easiest and most reliable way of doing this is to pass the images using Base64 strings.

I have included example functions for sending and retrieving images using Mathematica .NETLink. The .NETLink built in function for retrieving images (EvaluateToImage) seems to re-encode the image.

Once the image is back in a byte array, saving or displaying the image should be trivial.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Wolfram.NETLink;

namespace Example
{
    class Example
    {
        private static IKernelLink ml;

        internal void InitializeKernelLink()
        {
            ml = MathLinkFactory.CreateKernelLink();
            ml.WaitAndDiscardAnswer();
        }

        internal void SendImage()
        {        
            var path = @"C:\Example.JPG";
            var imageArray = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            var base64Image = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);
            ml.Evaluate("importedImage = ImportString[\"" + base64Image + "\",\"Base64\"]");
            ml.WaitAndDiscardAnswer();
        }

        internal void GetImage()
        {
            ml.Evaluate($"ExportString[importedImage,{{\"Base64\", \"PNG\"}}]");
            ml.WaitForAnswer();
            var data = ml.GetString();
            byte[] decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
        }

    }
}
```